# Loop not exiting

Tags: java, loops

I have been given a piece of code that is both overly-complicated and severely inefficient. My task is to:

- Determine why the loop will not exit
- Re-factor this code so it is more efficient.

  ```
          do
          {
              if(noOfQuest<1)
              {
                  System.out.println("FILE_ERROR: Please ensure line \"noOfEmails\" is more than 0");
              }

              if(noOfQuest==1)
              {
                  if(iCount==0)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                      System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                      ansArray[0]=ans.next();
                      System.out.println("Answer 1 where question is ["+noOfQuest+"]" +ansArray[0]);
                      if(IsAnswer1Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure you enter a response");
                          continue;
                      }
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
              }
              if(noOfQuest==2)
              {
                  if(iCount==0)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                      ansArray[0]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer1Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you enter a response for question 1");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==1)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                      System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                      ansArray[1]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer2Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you enter a response for question 2");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
              }

              if(noOfQuest==3)
              {
                  if(iCount==0)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on [" +iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                      ansArray[0]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer1Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you enter a response for question 1");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==1)
                  {
                      System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                      ansArray[1]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer2Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 2");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==2)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                      System.out.println(questionArr[2]);
                      ansArray[2]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer3Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 3");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
              }
              if(noOfQuest==4)
              {
                  if(iCount==0)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on [" +iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                      ansArray[0]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer1Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you enter a response for question 1");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==1)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on [" +iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                      ansArray[1]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer2Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 2");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==2)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[2]);
                      ansArray[2]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer3Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 3");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==3)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                      System.out.println(questionArr[3]);
                      ansArray[3]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer4Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 3");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
              }
              if(noOfQuest==5)
              {
                  if(iCount==0)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on [" +iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                      ansArray[0]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer1Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you enter a response for question 1");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==1)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on [" +iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                      ansArray[1]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer2Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 2");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==2)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[2]);
                      ansArray[2]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer3Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 3");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==3)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(questionArr[3]);
                      ansArray[3]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer4Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 4");
                          continue;
                      }
                      iCount++;
                      System.out.println(finalMess);
                  }
                  if(iCount==4)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Count is on ["+iCount+"]");
                      System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                      System.out.println(questionArr[4]);
                      ansArray[4]=ans.next();
                      if(IsAnswer5Blank(ansArray)==true)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that you have entered a response for question 5");
                          continue;
                      }
                  }
                  iCount++;
                  System.out.println(finalMess);
              }
              if(iCount==0)
              {
                  if(noOfQuest==0)
                  {
                      System.out.println("FILE_ERROR: Please ensure line \"noOfQuest\" in file is between 1 and 5." + "\n" +
                                          "File located: C:/Exercise 7 - Emails/configuration.properties");
                  }
                  iCount++;
                  if(noOfQuest>5)
                  {
                      System.out.println("FILE_ERROR: Please ensure line \"noOfQuest\" in file is between 1 and 5." + "\n" +
                                          "File located: C:/Exercise 7 - Emails/configuration.properties");
                  }
                  iCount++;
              }
              if(iCount==1)
              {
                  break;
              }

              break;
          }
          while(true);
  ```

When the variable "noOfQuest" is set as "0", the aplication closes as expected. When the variable is set to anything more than 5 however, the application hangs.
How can I fix this?

### EDIT

I have edited the question to include the answer I ended up using, suggested by Lawrence Aiello below (accepted answer).

```
if(iCount==0)
            {
                if(noOfQuest==0 || noOfQuest>5)
                {
                    System.out.println("FILE_ERROR: Please ensure line \"noOfQuest\" in file is greater than 0." + "\n" +
                                        "File located: C:/Exercise 7 - Emails/configuration.properties");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
```

Refactored into a for-nested do-while loop to check all conditions

Comment: When you find yourself copying a piece of the code again and again - it's time to refactor!

Comment: Maybe you can change your loop to a `do {...} while (noOfQuests <=5)`?

Comment: @alfasin Unfortunately for this exercise, refactoring isn't an option, but good idea

Comment: @Keppil Good suggestion, but having already tried it, my conditionals didn't work 100%

Comment: @DrewKennedy Time to use a health potion, or load from checkpoint?

Comment: @MichaelWiggins - why isn't refactoring an option?

Comment: @Ascalonian Because my mentor has a sick sense of humour, and thought it would be of benefit for me to go without simpler routes.

Comment: @MichaelWiggins - If he is forcing you to write inefficient code, too bad you can't ask for a new mentor haha.

Comment: So you have to do it all in one method, and can't outsource the common code to a helper method?? That is sick, and contrary to good programming.

Comment: "When the variable is set to anything more than 5 however, the application hangs" - but you never describe the wanted behavior. You can do many things when you reach: `if(noOfQuest>5)`: 1. `break`  2. `return` 3. set `noOfQuest` to a value lower than 5...

Comment: @dcsohl I can and have implemented helper methods, each of these are in the class in which they are used. Other than that, there isn't much external aid.

Comment: @alfasin noOfQuest is a variable pulled and parsed from a properties file, and a change here would mess with the application. I did however find a nice tidy way of closing out the application without issue, as per my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have your program in an infinite while loop that only exits when `noOfQuest` is 0. Therefore, if it never reaches this value, the loop will continue on forever, which results in the hanging you are talking about.

Put an if statement in there that handles values greater than 5 for `noOfQuest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you systematically check different discrete values (1, 2, 3,...) use a switch case statement. Also add a default path so you never get stuck. Saves you a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I came across was the following piece of code:

```
if(iCount==0)
                {
                    if(noOfQuest==0 || noOfQuest>5)
                    {
                        System.out.println("FILE_ERROR: Please ensure line \"noOfQuest\" in file is greater than 0." + "\n" +
                                            "File located: C:/Exercise 7 - Emails/configuration.properties");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
```

This section checks if iCount is 0 (always is at runtime) and checks if the number of questions is 0 OR more than 5. If it is, it will print the message and close the application, using "System.exit(0)". This command closses the current JVM Session.

Comment: Like I wrote above, there are many things you could do: break, return, throw an exception etc.